# is it possible nvd3 multibar chart with viewfinder?

Tags: java, javascript, html, nvd3.js

currently in my project i want to include chart functionality like bar, line pie etc. i am using nvd3 chart library now but the thing is i want multibar chart with view finder. the multibar chart is like this http://nvd3.org/ghpages/multiBar.html and i want that multibar chart to be like this with view finder in the bottom http://nvd3.org/ghpages/lineWithFocus.html
I goggled for 4 days but haven't get any thing can some one could help in this